# What kind of data volumes processing is Kafka more suited for? I am looking for numbers here

Tags: apache-kafka

I am relatively new to Kafka and have read that Kafka is suited for use cases where fast processing of high volumes of data is required, like Web Activity tracking. Can someone give me some numbers, like for ~ n TPS(Transaction Per Second) it makes sense to use Kafka whereas for ~ k TPS, something simple life a messaging queue would suffice? Since Kafka has an overhead of resources required, high maintenance so trying to figure when to go the Kafka route and when to stick to MQ.

Comment: TPS without context is meaningless, and is likely not the question to ask. It’s like asking about RPM without consideration the torque, gearing, usage, etc.. that is, it’s an end to a means.

Comment: Also, now quite sure why Kafka would be considered to have higher overhead/maintenance than “MQ” (which one?, as Kafka is _also_ a “MQ”).

Comment: Ok, TPS may not be the most accurate term, but hope you get the idea that I am looking for some numbers that specify what kind of load we are talking about when we say that Kafka is suited for "high volume data processing". If you have a better wording feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: For your second comment, have a look at this link https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-key-challenges-developers-face-while-getting-started-with-Kafka-Confluent. Also, by "MQ" I meant traditional messagings service, for example ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ.